# Session Variable in Select Statement

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

On one page i have it to show the user who logged in username which works perfectly fine.

```
echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']
```

I wanna create a Select Statement which uses the same variable as above to pull all data for that user.

Example Username is jsmith@gmail.com

**I used this to see if the coding works which it did.**

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE myusername ='jsmith@gmail.com'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

**But I wanna use the variable; I tried the code below but it didn't work.**

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE myusername ='$_SESSION['username']'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

I know for sure it has to do with the SELECT statement using the variable, im not sure if i am relating to the variable correctly.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are missing a double quote at the end of the $sql assignment

Comment: You are missing your closing double quote - `$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE myusername ='$_SESSION['username']';` needs to be `$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE myusername ='$_SESSION['username']'";`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE myusername ='{$_SESSION['username']}'";
```

This syntax where you use the variable replacement capacity of PHP in string is much easier to read, at-least when you have to replace multiple variables in a string.

Comment: Cleaner than what I answered.

Comment: Beautiful. I hate messing around with dots and double-quotes. I'll use this syntax for ever more.

Answer (score 2):

Basic PHP syntax rules: When embedding an array reference in a string, you do NOT use quotes on the keys:

```
echo "$arr['key']";   // wrong
echo "$arr[key]";     // right
echo "{$arr['key']}"; // right
```

Note that the `{}` syntax is REQUIRED if you're embedding a multi-dimensional array:

```
echo "$arr[foo][bar]";
```

is parsed as

```
echo $arr['foo'];
echo '[bar]';
```

Adding the `{}` makes PHP use the entire array key sequence:

```
echo "{$arr['foo']['bar']}";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your returning a string of myusername = $_SESSION['username'], when you actually need whats stored in that. Remove the '' and append the variable to the string.

Something like this:

$sql= 'SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE myusername = ' . $_SESSION['username'] . '';

Comment: @andrewsi Yeah, sorry wasn't clear on what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_task where username =  '".$_SESSION['username']."' ORDER By DateAssigned ASC ");
```

Comment: There is a SQL injection problem with your answer. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username ='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
$result=mysqli_query($sql);
```

Try this ........

100% it will work.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

You have not ended your query:-

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE myusername ='$_SESSION['username']'; // double quotes missing
```

Even the `Stackoverflow` code highlighter shows it.

Answer (score 0):

`$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE myusername ='$_SESSION[username]'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);`

Corrected code above.

There will be no quotes for username inside session.